# serializer_field_mapping DRF

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to understand how

```
serializer_field_mapping
```

works in Django Rest Framework and how to properly use it (in the context of the following code).

I have this code:
# models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

# serializers.py

```
class CustomCharField(serializers.CharField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return f"!!!{str(value)}!!!"
```

```
class TestModelSerializerTwo(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ["id", "name", "number"]
        serializer_field_mapping = {
            models.CharField: CustomCharField,
        }
```

The **desirable output** when calling serializer.data would be adding "!!!" before and after the CharField value (it does not work with my previous code)

```
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "!!!name1!!!",
        "number": 2
    }
```

But I really do now know how to properly use it.

I tried this:

```
class TestModelSerializerTwo(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        field_mapping = serializers.ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping
        field_mapping[models.CharField] = CustomCharField

        setattr(self.Meta, 'serializer_field_mapping', field_mapping)

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ["id", "name", "number", "edited_name"]
```

It gave me this:

```
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "!!!name1!!!",
        "number": 2
    }
```

But is this the correct way of using **serializer_field_mapping**, (because it doesn't seem to follow the best practices in my case with overwriting **init**)? Could you please give and advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do this without overriding the `init()` method of the serializer. Notice that we can make a copy of the `serializer_field_mapping` (which is a dictionary) and then assign `charField` to `CustomCharField`. Here is the complete code to achieve this:

#serializers.py

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers

from djangoProject.models import TestModel


class CustomCharField(serializers.CharField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return f"!!!{str(value)}!!!"

class TestModelSerializerTwo(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serializer_field_mapping = (
        serializers.ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping.copy()
    )
    serializer_field_mapping[models.CharField] = CustomCharField

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ["id", "name", "number"]
```

#views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from djangoProject.serializers import TestModelSerializerTwo


class TestView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestModelSerializerTwo

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, data=serializer.data)
```